# Detecting memory leakage in Ruby

Tags: ruby, memory

How to check memory leakage of Ruby program on ubuntu?

Comment: I edited your title to reflect your the edit you just did. In the future, ask a new question instead of editing your old, unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can periodically force garbage collection using `GC.start`:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/GC.html#method-c-start

Upon doing so, use `ObjectSpace.count_objects` to know the number of objects remaining:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-count_objects