# How to garbage collect ruby objects between requests in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am currently looking into memory leakage issue for an existing huge application (ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.0.19).
For finding out the main problem areas, I used [oink](https://github.com/noahd1/oink) gem which is a Log parser to identify actions which significantly increase VM heap size. Using this I was able to optimize the code accordingly.

But is there a way we can garbage collect the freed ruby objects between requests so that the memory is cleared up as and when required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if symbols are used more, try to reduce their usage. GC I think ruby 2.2 has got it by default, 1.8.7 seems very old.

Comment: Not what you are looking for but checkout [`memory swaping`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04), it can  increase the responsiveness of your server and guard against out of memory errors

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses @Nithin As per the current scenario, we can't upgrade the application to ruby 2.2

Comment: Thanks @Mandeep I was looking for a way if we can clear the memory once the request is completed, something like manually triggering the garbage collector.Suppose, inside the application we have a huge hash object which I want to clear once that particular action is completed.Is it possible to achieve something like this in ruby 1.8.7

Comment: @EktaVerma if you can narrow down that action which is causing memory clutter then you can write some script to kill that process manually and free up server memory. If you can't then your best bet would be to simply increase your server memory and manually reboot system to kill that process. Btw first try to find out why is that process taking so much memory anyways? There must be something wrong in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Please go through below documentation link

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/GC.html

Also you can check similar question asked by me

[Detecting memory leakage in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258370/detecting-memory-leakage-in-ruby)

Hopefully this will help.